# Whats another word for someone perceptive?

Tags: word-choice

Whats another word to describe someone who can pick up on things quickly?

Comment: Welcome. I suggest 'quick on the uptake.'  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/quick+on+the+uptake

Answer (score 3):

> [***astute***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/astute) :
> keenly perceptive or discerning; sagacious. <sup>1</sup>

or

> [***perspicacious***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perspicacious) :
>
> - Having or showing penetrating mental discernment; clear-sighted.<sup>2</sup>
> - acutely perceptive or discerning<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub><sup>Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.</sup></sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub><sup>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sup></sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub><sup>Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003</sup></sub>

Comment: I definitely like astute.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "observant" works here?  I don't know that it reflects your "pick up on things quickly" though.

> [observant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/observant) (adjective)
>
> good at watching and listening : good at noticing what is going on around you
>
> careful to follow religious teachings or customs

Answer (score 0):

If you want a noun, *quick learner* or, more old-fashioned, *quick study*.  Usage: She's a quick study OR she's a quick learner.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities:

- Quick-witted man,
- A man sharp as a tack,
- Man of keen/sharp/alert intellect/mind,
- Man with a vivacious spirit,
- Quick/swift thinking man.